# pandas apply filter for boolean type

Tags: python, pandas

These are the types for my DataFrame;

```
count     int64
word     object
cat1       bool
cat2     object
cat3       bool
dtype: object
```

How do I do a filter for boolean values from 'cat1' and 'cat2'?

Something like...

```
data[(data['cat1'].bool() == FALSE) & (data['cat3'].bool() == FALSE)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do:

```
data[(data['cat1'] == FALSE) & (data['cat2'] == FALSE)]
```

`cat2` is an `object` `dtype` so it is probably a string, I think you want:

```
data[(data['cat1'] == FALSE) & (data['cat3'] == FALSE)]
```

otherwise if it really is string values then you can do

```
data[(data['cat1'] == FALSE) & (data['cat2'] == 'FALSE')]
```

or

```
data[(data['cat1'] == FALSE) & (data['cat2'].str.contains('FALSE'))]
```

Comment: For Python 3+ (at least), you have to get the casing right on the bools -- so you'd write `'FALSE'` for the string values (assuming that they're uppercase in the DataFrame), but `False` for the bool values

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this,

```
data[(data['cat1']==False) & (data['cat3']==False)]
```

Example:

```
test = pd.DataFrame({'word':'','cat1':bool(),'cat2':'','cat3':bool()},index=[])
test.loc[0]=['test1',True,'try',False]
test.loc[1]=['test1',False,'try',False]
test[(test['cat1']==False) & (test['cat3']==False)]
```